# Dmesg shows segfaults on almost all system applications

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault

Our team has a server equipped with couple of GPUs.
We've installed Ubuntu 20.04 on it to run couple of experiments.
However, we've experienced random segfaults without running any custom programs of our own.
The random segfaults happens even during `apt updates`.

We looked through `dmesg` to check what was causing the segfault.
Here is the output of `dmesg`.
[image: screenshot of dmesg]

As shown, default applications such as gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, systemd-temdat, apport are all causing segfaults.

Can we conclude that this is an hardware problem? If it is, which hardware should most likely cause this kind of segfaults? We'd like to swap out faulty component with a new one.

We've reinstalled Ubuntu multiple times due to unknown segmentation faults, but we still see this happen.

Comment: Explore this. Remove GPUs, try it this way. Perform memory, CPU tests. Try switching memory modules, and so on. All in all, this question is likely off topic on serverfault.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that its not the correct spot to ask this question. However, after hours of searching, I landed upon a tool called ```memtester``` which finds bad memory addresses. I'll try this and see if it shows a consistent memory failure. If it does fail on the same locations, I presume that its the bad RAM. If it not, it would be power supply or any other hardware that is keep generating this.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov We have always accepted HPC questions here, although there aren't many people who can answer them. The OP is welcome to try [unix.se] where it should also be on topic. There is still missing information though, such as a full description of the server hardware.

Comment: For random segfaults, first thing I'd test is indeed RAM. I had RAM that was bad where testing with `memtester` etc. didn't show any problems. I debugged this by swapping/removing the RAM modules. Buying new RAM made the problem go away. This may or may not apply to your situation.